# How can i solve the javascript map problem in a array

Tags: javascript

I'm still at my card game. Again and again I have such places as now where I can't get any further.
I have two hands with cards. I want to output the names and suits as an array. But that only works with a two-digit combination. As soon as there is a 10 it is three digits and it no longer works.

```
'use strict'

let hand1 = ['7H', '2H', 'QH', '9H', '5H']
let hand2 = ['7H', '2H', 'QH', '10H', '5H']

let toSuit = hand => hand.map(a => a[0])
let toName = hand => hand.map(a => a[1])



console.log(toName(hand1))
console.log(toSuit(hand1))

console.log(toName(hand2))
console.log(toSuit(hand2))
```

I can do that for the single card but not for the output as an array.

```
'use strict'
    
let card1 = '9H'
let card2 = '10H'
  
let toSuit1 = card => card.charAt(card.length - 1)
let toName1 = card => card.slice(0,-1)  
   
console.log(toSuit1(card1))
console.log(toSuit1(card2))

console.log(toName1(card1))
console.log(toName1(card2))
```

Thanks @blex

```
'use strict'

let hand1 = ['7H', '2H', 'QH', '9H', '5H']
let hand2 = ['7H', '2H', 'QH', '10H', '5H']

let toSuit1 = card => card.charAt(card.length - 1);
let toName1 = card => card.slice(0,-1); 

let toSuit = hand => hand.map(toSuit1)
let toName = hand => hand.map(toName1)

console.log(toName(hand1))
console.log(toSuit(hand1))

console.log(toName(hand2))
console.log(toSuit(hand2))
```

Comment: You have all the pieces, now join them together: `toSuit = hand => hand.map(toSuit1); toName = hand => hand.map(toName1);`

Comment: @blex I've been sitting on the problem for more than an hour. Simply together. LOL. I was only focused on a [0]. I find it really difficult to see these simple things all the time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could just take the functions for mapping.

```js
'use strict';

const
    toSuit = card => card.charAt(card.length - 1),
    toName = card => card.slice(0,-1),
    toSuits = hand => hand.map(toSuit),
    toNames = hand => hand.map(toName),

    hand1 = ['7H', '2H', 'QH', '9H', '5H'],
    hand2 = ['7H', '2H', 'QH', '10H', '5H'];

console.log(...toNames(hand1))
console.log(...toSuits(hand1))

console.log(...toNames(hand2))
console.log(...toSuits(hand2))
```